# what is the range of octal escape sequence in c?

Tags: c, escaping, octal

```
Code
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i;
printf("%d \n",'\1');
printf("%d \n",'\022');
printf("%d ",'\555');
return 0;
}
```

Output:
1
18
109

When we compile this program then gcc compiler gives warning '\555' is octal escape sequence out of range? What is this range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upper limit is usually 255, which is `'\377'`. This assumes an eight-bit char type, which is not guaranteed by C, but is a safe assumption in most environments.

Answer (score 7):

From the C99 spec, §6.4.4.4 Paragraph 9:

> The value of an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence shall be in the
>   range of representable values for the type unsigned char for an
>   integer character constant, or the unsigned type corresponding to
>   wchar_t for a wide character constant.